# Not adding a new post?

Tags: posts, forms

I am trying to add a new post via the front form. This is how it looks:
I insert the form in the right place via `get_template_part`, here is the form itself:

```
    <form class="consult__form-q" id="consultations-form" action="" method="post">
    <label>Задать вопрос</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    <input name="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input name="theme" type="text" placeholder="Тема" required>
    <textarea name="text"  placeholder="Задайте свой вопрос тут" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Задать вопрос</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted">
</form>
<?php submit_consultations_form() ?>
```

Here is the handler function itself, I put it in `function.php`, I checked it for sure:

```
    function submit_consultations_form()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {


        $post_data = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['theme']),
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['text']),
            'post_author'   => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['name']),
            'post_type'      => 'questions',
        );


        $post_id = wp_insert_post( wp_slash($post_data) );

        }


}
```

The problem is that the new post is simply not being added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your hidden input has no value, is that intentional? When `wp_insert_post` fails it returns a `WP_Error` object with an error message, did you check for this? If so what did it say the problem was?

Comment: @TomJNowell First, 1) No, I don't know if it matters. I just wrote that.
2) Where or how can I see this message?

Comment: If `wp_insert_post` fails it returns a `WP_Error` object rather than a post ID, so the `$post_id` variable would be the error object. You can use `is_wp_error()` to test for this, look up `WP_Error` on the official docs at .org for how to retrieve the message